# Vector Equation of a Plane (Parametric)

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, parametric

I am currently learning about creating the vector equation for a line parametrically from using the Point-Direction form of a line. (If that makes sense, please correct my understanding/wording). I understand how to find the vector equation of a line given 2 points.

(Ex. https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-vector-equation-of-a-line-when-given-two-points).

But I am confused as to how this question works as it deals with a plane instead of a line.

```
Use vector notation to describe the points that lie in the given configuration. (Let s and t be elements of the Reals.)

the plane spanned by 
**v**1 = (8, 4, 0)
 and 
**v**2 = (0, 8, 4)

Answer: **l**(s,t) = (8s, 4s + 8t, 4t)
```

Comment: Looks like it talks about setting up a vector equation of a plane, not a line

Comment: Yes, look @ line above question. EDIT: nvm changed the title, sorry

Comment: Do you understand how the point-direction form of parametric equation for a line works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plane in $R^3$ that's equivalent to span$(v_1,v_2)$ is $$\left\{x|x = sv_1 + tv_2 = s\left( \begin{array}{c} 8 \\ 4\\ 0 \end{array}\right) + t  \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 8\\ 4 \end{array}\right) =  \left( \begin{array}{c} 8s \\ 4s+8t\\ 4t \end{array}\right)\right\}.$$